# React router v4 - Login router Home Page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I'm working with `react-router v4` and I haven't been able to redirect from the login component to the main page (index), this is an example of my code with a button to redirect direct.

*Login.js*

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.history.push('/home');
}

<button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
    Navigate
</button>
```

*Index.js*

```
ReactDOM.render((
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>
                    <Login>
                        <div>
                            <SearchBar/>
                            <MainMenu/>
                        </div>
                         <Switch>
                            <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
                            <Route path="/calendar" component={Calendar}/>
                            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                         </Switch>
                         <Footer/>
                    </Login>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Router>
</Provider>
),document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `<Redirect>` component?

Comment: Try using props instead of context: `this.props.router.push('/some/path')`

Comment: I think your solutions are right, when I use it inside the main menu it works, but not from login!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: Using Link**

For a simple solution, you can use `Link` component from `react-router-dom`, instead of button in your `Login.js`. There are ways to change the route in JS, but this seems easier one.

You need to import Login first:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and then replace your `<button>` and `handleClick()` with this:

```
<span className="someclass">
  <Link to="/home" />Navigate</Link>
</span>
```

**Solution 2: Using Redirect**

```
<Redirect exact from='/' to='/home' />
```

P.S. In your current code setup you could also try using `this.props.history.push('/home')` in your `handleClick()` instead of `this.context.router.history.push('/home')`.